# Phonegap Download html File and replace it (source)

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, download

i'm tring to figure out how to replace or add some of the source files of Phonegap with the a downloaded file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
               function onBodyLoad()
            {
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            }

            function downloadFile(){
                window.requestFileSystem(
                                         LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
                                         function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
                                         fileSystem.root.getFile(
                                                                 "dummy.html", {create: true, exclusive: false},
                                                                 function gotFileEntry(fileEntry){
                                                                 var sPath = fileEntry.fullPath.replace("dummy.html","");
                                                                 var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
                                                                 fileEntry.remove();

                                                                 fileTransfer.download(
                                                                                       "https://dl.dropbox.com/u/xxxxx/index_2.html",
                                                                                       sPath + "index_aerosoft.html",
                                                                                       function(theFile) {
                                                                                       console.log("download complete: " + theFile.toURI());
                                                                                       showLink(theFile.toURI());
                                                                                       },
                                                                                       function(error) {
                                                                                       console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                                                                                       console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                                                                                       console.log("upload error code: " + error.code);
                                                                                       }
                                                                                       );
                                                                 },
                                                                 fail);
                                         }, 
                                         fail);

            }

            function showLink(url){
                alert(url);
                var divEl = document.getElementById("ready");
                var aElem = document.createElement("a");
                aElem.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
                aElem.setAttribute("href", url);
                aElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Ready! Click To Open."))
                divEl.appendChild(aElem);

            }


            function fail(evt) {
                console.log(evt.target.error.code);
            }

            function onDeviceReady()
            {
                downloadFile();
            }

            </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
            <br />
            <p>
            DOWNLOADING FILE...<br />
            <span id="ready"></span>
            </p>
            </body>
</html>
```

I can download and access the file but can i somewhere set the path of download to the 'www' folder in Phonegap?
Or how i figure out what the the path of the file (so i can link to that path)

Xcode Console tells me 
`file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/1AE34410-C57E-4896-8616-042E386552E0/Documents/index_2.html`

Can i somehow link to that?

Comment: You cannot overwrite files that are bundled in the app. You can only write to locations on the persistent storage.

Answer (score 4):

you can't replace the code in source ...
because the android asset folder is read-only
and the html you have written places there ...
if you can program java i suggest coping html files from assets to sdcard then running the code from there
you can modify it then

**Or you can store downloaded HTML in HTML5 Local Storage:**

I did this in phonegap-build (in dreamweaver) and it worked for me:

```
// retrive html data as String in Var : MY_Data
window.localStorage.setItem("mydiv_update", My_Data);
document.getElementById("your_div").innerHtml = My_Data;
```

then each time the page is loading check if `window.localStorage.getItem("mydiv_update")` exists. if yes then change the div's innetHTML . like this :

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem("mydiv_update")){
  document.getElementById("your_div").innerHtml = window.localStorage.getItem("mydiv_update");
}
```

and don't forget storage permissions :

***Permissions***

---

**Android**

app/res/xml/config.xml :

```
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer" />
```

app/AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

**Bada**

No permissions are required.

---

**BlackBerry WebWorks**

www/plugins.xml :

```
<plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileManager" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.http.FileTransfer" />
```

www/config.xml :

```
<feature id="blackberry.io.file" required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
<feature id="blackberry.utils"   required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
<feature id="blackberry.io.dir"  required="true" version="1.0.0.0" />
<rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>
```

---

**iOS :**
config.xml :

```
<plugin name="File" value="CDVFile" />
<plugin name="FileTransfer" value="CDVFileTransfer" />
```

---

**webOS :**
No permissions are required.

---

**Windows Phone :**
No permissions are required.