# Download HTML to iOS persistent storage and load/navigate to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I've just started using Phonegap with iOS and I'm wondering if there's a way to update the look of the application remotely (forgetting about App Store updates in this case).

I know that I can store data in a local database on the device and in files, but I'd like to navigate to that downloaded file. My app would start and check for updated HTML and JS files on my server. If there were none, it would continue to use the HTML already saved on the device. I don't want to navigate straight to a page on my server as Apple native APIs wouldn't work and I want the app to work offline too. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399918/phonegap-download-html-file-and-replace-it-source) existing Stackoverflow question asking for something similar and persistent storage was mentioned by a commenter. I want to find out if it's possible to navigate to something in persistent storage.

Is it possible to download a HTML with Phonegap/Apache Cordova and then navigate to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is YES.

- You'll need a FileTransfer,
- then store the file to the filesystem
- You have to store the absolute path in the local-storage and navigate to it

I'am pretty sure, that this app will be removed from the apple-app store, because loading code from a server is prohibited.

Apple will remove this app from the store.

Comment: I thought it was more of a problem if you just load a website and display it as an app. Then apple will remove the app. But this is different if you only load a new site once and a while, so it may pass?